# Why not n-tuples instead of functions for cartesian product of infinite indexed family of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, products

Following is the definition of Infinite Cartesian Products.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

For cartesian product, why do not we just use cartesian product and get "n-tuples" instead of "arbitrary(possibly infinite) indexed family" of function sets?

I am not sure but the reason might be that there is not any usual way to select from tuples unless a function used so functions used in first place. (Actually there is projection map definition in wiki article but not sure about it.)
(This answer is also about n-tuple item access;  [Mathematical symbol to reference the i-th item in a tuple?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31889/mathematical-symbol-to-reference-the-i-th-item-in-a-tuple))

So, is not there any way other than functions to access n-tuple items?
So, what is the point actually?

Comment: What exactly *is* an "$n$-tuple" when $n$ is infinite? The point is that we actually want to think of ordinary finite tuples themselves as functions: a $2$-tuple, for example, is a function with domain $\{0,1\}$, whose value on $0$ is the $0$th coordinate and whose value on $1$ is the $1$st coordinate.

Comment: So, is it just because of that we cannot define an infinite n-tuple?

Comment: I wouldn't phrase it that way. Rather, I'd say that we haven't actually defined *finite tuples* in a sufficiently precise way. Try to define (say) a $3$-tuple in a precise way and I think you'll see the issue.

Comment: @NoahSchweber are not tuples necessarily ordered? So, i understand like this, they are distinct by order but when we are building/defining them, they do not have any order.

Comment: "Ordered" is a strong word, and isn't always applicable: sometimes we consider tuples indexed by sets which aren't ordered in any nice way (e.g. an $\mathbb{R}^2$-indexed tuple). Rather, a tuple *has distinguished coordinates*. This is really the crucial property: what a tuple does is answer questions of the form "What is your term with index $i$?," which is ... basically the same thing that a function does ("What is your value on input $i$?").

Comment: This pragmatic approach - basically, that a tuple *is* what it *does*, and can be generalized accordingly - is developed further in **category theory** via the notion of **universal properties**. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)#Definition) in particular.

Comment: @NoahSchweber So, we cannot set item at index i and could not read too, so what could we do with them? i am confused, have no sense in math but only in programming!?.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. A tuple is exactly a function: you feed it an index and it spits out a value. The language of "setting values" isn't really appropriate for math; in math, objects are *static*, not dynamic. (OK fine there are immutable objects in programming too, but in general there is a notion of "changing an object" in programming which isn't used in mathematics - my broader point is that programming-based ideas aren't always appropriate to math.)

Comment: (Re: static vs. dynamic definitions, see also the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3156504/28111).)

Comment: @NoahSchweber thanks, you're right.

Comment: @lockedscope: There was a user that insisted that we can prove the axiom of choice because we can apply a Python/JS like approach and if we have a collection of sets, we can simply `x.map((y)=>some element of y)`, "programming logic" can be misleading if you don't *really* think about the underlying math below the actual operations. Once you realise that the iteration is really just hiding a `for` loop, you can see that there will be some indexing and finite-to-infinite failure (because in a proof `for` or `while` get unfolded to their linear execution, in some sense). The same goes here.

Comment: So, when we try programmatic/algorithmic approach, we cannot solve it infinitely and so we cannot prove or reach to some result. Therefore, programmatic approaches are invalid for infinities.